# If condition on the div tags

Tags: html, css, salesforce, visualforce

How can I dynamically change the styling on the VisualForce Page depending on the Lightning/ Classic.As we are in the process of migrating from Classic to Lightning we want the VF page to be compatible in both the User Interfaces. I am trying to set the div tag based on the UI Theme detection

```
          <div style= "{IF($User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme3'? 'position:relative;left:150': 'position:relative;left:400px')}">
          <apex:outputLabel value="ABC"></apex:outputLabel>
          </div>
```

But there is no change in the Alignment, it just shows the text towards the left in both the UI

Comment: Is that correct syntax? I would guess you don't need the `IF(...)` surrounding the ternary operator...but am not very familiar with visualforce. Also you're missing your unit declaration on the first `left`. I would assume should be `150px`

Comment: Looks like ternaries might not work in visualforce, but the IF statement might work here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70104/how-to-use-ternary-operator-in-visual-force-page

Comment: @sallf is right. That's not valid syntax for the `IF()` function as well (it takes three parameters). Plus you're missing the `{!` opening token for a Visualforce expression.